# @Value in spring returns null

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, null

I have used @value in spring to load the values from properties to my java constants.

But am getting null as a value in constants. Help me out .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd" >

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epro.aemcrmsync" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/epro/aemcrmsync/properties/config.properties" />

</beans>
```

Class :

```
package com.epro.aemcrmsync.constants;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class ConfigConstants {


     @Value("$(field_name}")
    public static String USER_ID;

}
```

Comment: As noted in the answer, you cannot use static fields and second of all you should be using `@Value("${field_name}")` instead of `@Value("$(field_name}")`.

Comment: Still getting null only.Am using jersey implementation may be it seems problem is it right ? Even i injected value to xml but its not working one more thing is i didn't add dispatcherservlet in xml whether is it prob help me out.

Comment: I haven't used Jersey so I don't know what the problem could be

Comment: How did you solve it? Maybe you should answer your own question

Comment: Problem is with my configuration i.e., earlier control is fully with jersey container not spring container.For jersey spring integration there is class called com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet it take cares both spring and jersy earlier i used "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer" thats the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Spring does not process `static` members. Make the field an instance field. Inject the `ConfigConstants` bean anywhere you need to use it.

Comment: Additionally, the SpEL in the question is bad.

Comment: Still getting null only

Comment: @sridhar Edit your question and show us how you use the bean.

Comment: package com.epro.aemcrmsync.constants;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("configConstants")
public class ConfigConstants {
 
// @Value("#{config['aem_field_name']}") 
  @Value("${aem_field_name}")
 public String AEM_USER_ID;
 
}

Comment: this is my service class .. @Component(value="userService")
@Path("user")
public class UserService {
 
 
 @Autowired
 private ConfigConstants configConstants;

Comment: @sridhar **Edit your question**. What is `null` in the code you've shown? You seem to be using jersey or some other framework. Are you doing the integration with Spring correctly?

Comment: yes i done correctly this is my configuration file That injected object shows null <context:component-scan base-package="com.epro.aemcrmsync" />
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/epro/aemcrmsync/properties/config.properties" />

Comment: @sridhar **Stop posting code in comments. It is impossible to read.**

Comment: Okay what will be the problem??

Comment: @sridhar The problem seems to be that your spring-jersey integration is done incorrectly. The object you are looking at is created by jersey, not Spring.

Comment: yes thats correct but wat will be the solution for this issue?

Comment: @sridhar I don't know jersey. But it does have a Spring integration package. Look into that.

Comment: Remembered i have used @inject instead of autowired it works for me. But still gettting the property value as null